# SASS vanilla syntax highlight in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sass, visual-studio-extensions

I tried to install few extensions for highlight SASS syntax without braces `{}` and semicolons `;`, but didn't find anything, only for SCSS. Any advices?

```
body
    padding: 0px
    margin:  0px
main
    height: 100vh
```

Comment: I use one called Color Highlight. You might try that

Comment: I could not find related highlight syntax without braces, but you could write a custom highlight syntax without braces, for more information about custom highlight syntax, please refer to: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/657212c1-1685-4ed6-be2f-cbf34fcc5b20/adding-a-custom-language-just-for-syntax-highlighting?forum=vsx